# Is it necessary to allow access between different security groups in VPC on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-vpc

As the picture below, an EC2 and an ECS services are running on different subnet, target group and security groups. But they are in the same VPC.

[image]

I want to allow access the ECS service through EC2's Nginx server from public internet.

EC2 is allowing 80 and 443 now. And the ECS' security group is allowing 80 only. The Nginx's config is

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx.conf
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    proxy_pass          {{ internal_ecs_elb_endpoint }};
    proxy_read_timeout  60s;
    proxy_redirect      {{ internal_ecs_elb_endpoint }} myproxy.mydomain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Does the security group2 in ECS service need to allow security group1's tcp 80/443 port? As they are in the different groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the security group2 in ECS service need to allow security group1's tcp 80/443 port?

Yes. To follow good practice you would create inbound tcp rule for port 80 in SG2 with source of SG1.

Comment: Thank you. I added SG1's ID to SG2. But when I test the traffic, from domain it got
`https://myproxy.mydomain.com (edited) -> 504 DNS look up failed`
When I tried to use the public ALB before EC2 to access, it got
`https://proxy-11111111.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/ (edited) -> 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable`. It seems there is some issue between DNS and public ALB. How to diagnose it?

Comment: @Miantian I would suggest making new question with details of your dns and elb setup. Its difficult to speculate without those.

Comment: Thank you. I created a new one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69478387/how-to-set-up-a-reverse-proxy-server-with-alb-on-aws