# How to set up a reverse proxy server with alb on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, ssl

I created a service publish structure as below

[image]

I don't know why can't access the domain successfully. Where maybe the issue?

---

The public LB's listener rules are

[image]

Comment: Why do you have Nginx ec2 instance, if you use ALBs?

Comment: @Marcin We just want to test this pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add HTTP to HTTPS redirect config in the Loadbalancer rule itself.
[image]

To proxy your HTTPS requests to Applications server

```
server {
  listen       80 default_server;
  server_name  _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass <internal_loadbalancer_dns_name>;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I added my current public LB's listener rules to the bellow of the question. It seems 80' IF isn't set to /*. I want to use redirect to 443. If by your way, how to set a path?

Comment: I found the target group is unhealthy. I set the EC2's IP to it directly. EC2 is in the private subnet, the target group is in the public subnet's ALB. So they can't communicate?
- https://imgur.com/a/7Crag5l
- https://imgur.com/a/gf0hmzq

Comment: @Miantian You need to add load balancer security group to EC2 instance's security inbound rule to allow requests.